# Two tags for viruses

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, we have tag [virology](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virology) and tag [virus](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virus). Shouldn't one be a synonym of the other?

Comment: I don't think they're synonyms. One is a field of study while the other is the thing being studied. Closely related but not really synonyms.

Comment: @CareyGregory True, but why would anyone ask questions about the field of virology on Medical Sciences SE? Those would be more on-topic at Biology SE. I did also split hairs at [this question](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1195/12704), which was utterly ignored. Since the plural is used for tag [tag:bacteria] (there is no tag for bacteriology), for the sake of consistency, one could have tag [tag:viruses] instead of tag [tag:virus]. Since one is interested in virology in the context of medicine, one could also have tag [tag:medical-virology].

Comment: I didn't notice the prior question. I disagree on that one for different reasons.

Comment: I took a look and there are 40 questions tagged with [tag:virology]. A quick sampling shows that most of them aren't really about virology and should have used [tag:virus] instead, What I'd rather do is just delete [tag:virology] altogether, but doing that requires editing all the questions that use it and removing the tag. I **really** don't want  anyone to do that because that will hoist 40 questions to the top of the active list and drown out newer questions. So I'm going to just vote no on this one, meaning I'd rather see it left as is.

Comment: @CareyGregory I don't understand. Are you more concerned about the distinction between the field of study (virology) and that which is being studied (viruses) than in readers finding content easily and quickly? And amidst a **viral** pandemic? Respectfully, but isn't that a bit too perfectionist?

Comment: No, I'm simply not convinced that making these synonyms will help anyone find things more easily and it grates on my language perfectionism.

Comment: @CareyGregory Suppose I am a newbie here. Which I am. I find an answer with the tag [tag:virology] and then click on the tag to read the most upvoted questions on viruses. Unbeknownst to me, the content on viruses is mostly at [tag:virus].

Comment: Okay, you convinced me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggested change implemented .